# Exception while deserializing json string

Tags: json

```
While parsing json string as - {"reportingDate":[2017,4,30]}. 

I am getting com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
```

Below is the program -

JSON DESERIALIZING CODE -

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                            String dbString = "{\"reportingDate\":[2017,4,30]}";
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            // convert JSON string to Map
            map = mapper.readValue(dbString, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});

            System.out.println(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `JSON` mapping of type reference is wrong, `reportingDate` is `array` type but you are converting it as String

Change

```
map = mapper.readValue(dbString, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});
```

To

```
map = mapper.readValue(dbString, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
```